# Store Url in Session-Storage and redirect to that page angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, session, redirect, angular-ui-router

I want to redirect user to a page from where he had logged out. I am using `sessionStorage` to store the url and data which is required to redirect to that page. 
On log In User goes to a page and then from there he click a button and there I have three tabs where he goes to the first tab. When user is on that tab then on logout and If he again logs in then he should directly go to that tab .

My code is like -

```
.state('default.upload',{
      url: 'upload',
      views:{
        'moduleContainer@default':{
          templateUrl: 'partials/upload.html',
          controller: 'uploadController'
        },
        'header@default': getDefaultHeaderConfig()
      }
    }).state('default.orphans',{
      url: 'orphans?documentType',
      // loaded into ui-view of parent's template
      views:{
        'moduleContainer@default':{
          templateUrl: 'partials/orphan.html',
          controller: 'orphanController',
          params: {
            'documentType': 'resume'
          }
        },
        'header@default': getDefaultHeaderConfig()
      }
    })
```

When Users logs in the he goes to the `default.upload`.

After `logout`

```
$scope.logout = function() {
       sessionStorage.setItem('url',window.location.href);
       $state.go('default.login')
}
```

Here I am storing the current url in the sessionStorage.

And on login,

```
$scope.submit = function(loginFormData) { 
      // Here currently is  this is happening
     //  $state.go('default.upload');
   //I am getting the sessionStorage url 
   sessionStorage.getItem('url');
   // I want to redirect the user to this page. This page is the default.orphans. 
   // On this page In state there is only one param documenttype
   // When I go to this default.orphans by clicking on a button there is a service call  which takes some params and the get the response. 
   //`http://localhost/abc/reports/resume//undefined` 
   //is the service call so, I am also storing the params while log out. 
}
```

I am not getting how to use that params and do all the service calls on the login itself. Can any one explain me this ?

Comment: Are you asking how to pass parameters into a state via `$state.go` or is your goal to call the service and you just don't know how to use promises/access an HTTP API with Angular?

Comment: Actually I know how to pass parameters via $state.go

Comment: Could you restate your question then? I’m not sure what exactly it is that you want to know/don’t understand.